# Get data of similar record in elastic search in million records

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity, elasticsearch-5, mlt

Can We use MLT concept of ES to filter documents with similar fields.Is it possible to give weight to the individual field. What is elastic search recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html  According to your fields, this could be easy or difficult.

Comment: How to do it it elastic search java client . Please help .